# onClickListener for custom ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, onclicklistener

I'm having trouble adding an onClickListener to my custom list adapter, code below.
onListItemClick is implemented the same as a with a regular listView, but whenever an item is clicked nothing happens, except "unregisterListener....." appears in LogCat.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

MyListAdapter.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] names;

    static class ViewHolder {
        public Button button;
        public ImageButton imageButton;
        public ImageButton imageButton2;
    }

    public MyListAdapter(Activity context, String[] names) {
        super(context, R.layout.custom_list_item, names);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.button = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            viewHolder.imageButton = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.moreInfo);
            viewHolder.imageButton2 = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgArrow);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        String s = names[position];
        holder.button.setText(s);
        holder.imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.more);
        holder.imageButton2.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

customer_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/moreInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/more_info"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/more" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgArrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/select_trick"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: u want to add onClickListener on arrow button?

Comment: I want to add separate onClickListeners to arrow button and moreinfo button

Comment: If you want your arrow imagebutton to recieve onClick events, in your getView method, do something along the lines of: holder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(); Tip aside of that, rename the fields in your holder a reader actually knows what imageButton1 and imageButton2 do. For example rename one to imgArrow and the other to imgMoreInfo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add onClickListener on Arrow button,Write new class clicker like this

```
public class clicker implements View.OnClickListener
{
    int position=0;

    /*------- Constructor for storing position on which click event triggered  ----------*/
    public clicker(int pos)
    {
        position=pos;  //this will be position of selected item in listview.
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //Do your operation
    }

}
```

Call this Clicker in getView method ,

```
 holder.imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new clicker(position));
```

Use same procedure for moreinfo button

Comment: or .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //implement methods..});

Comment: Thanks for your help, I ended up using the above and adding this:
if(v.getId() == R.id.imgArrow){
  Log.d("debuggin", "arrow");
}else{
  Log.d("debuggin", "more");
}

inside onclick

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set an `OnClickListener` inside `getView()`?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...

    viewHolder.imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
          }
    };
    viewHolder.imageButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
          }
    };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

In your parent linear layout of your list row layout and your list row will get clicked

Comment: Weird this solution only makes some of the list item clickable